# Tear in RFs, not losing air

Tags: tires

[image]

Is this safe to drive on? Tire pressure has been same for days, and not losing air. Thanks all

Comment: Drive slowly to a tire center and replace it, that or put on a spare if you have one, Do It NOW.

Comment: **Don't drive on this tire**. Not fast, not slowly, don't drive. If you have a spare tire, use it for the drive to the workshop, if not, have your car lift towed. Damage like this can cause explosive failure any minute, which is a very dangerous thing to happen at any speed as it will inevitably freak you _and other drivers_ out, fire pieces of rubber in _their_ faces at high speed and cause other problems _you_ may be held liable for.

Comment: I once had a front tire blow out whilst doing approx 30mph. Before I even had chance to comprehend what was going on, the car was on the pavement, narrowly missing parked cars and a pedestrian. Somehow we managed to stop within millimeters from going through a garden wall. DO NOT drive on this for any reason other than taking it to the garage for a new tire.

Comment: Losing air is not the only problem a tyre can have. This one is going for a bang.

Answer (score 13):

That needs changing **NOW**

It is not safe even though it may not be loosing air it could fail at any mment...

Answer (score 13):

I can tell you that in the UK, it would fail an MOT inspection.  Specifically; 5.2.3 (d) (ii) "A tyre with a lump, bulge or tear caused by separation or partial failure of its structure"

Given that it would fail a UK MOT, I'd personally advise that in my view it is **not safe** to drive on.

Comment: If I'm not mistake UK laws do allow for driving a theoretically unsafe car (eg safe to drive a short distance but doesnt meet MOT standards), only on the provision that it is being driven to a place which is able to fix the problem at that time and in which an official appointment has been set. Also, I think that the location has to be within a reasonable drive (eg you've not ignored the 3 garages nearer to home that you could rake it to).

Comment: You are mistaken.  You are permitted to drive a car without an MOT to be inspected but it must not have any dangerous defects or you can be prosecuted for driving a dangerous vehicle.

Comment: You might want to read this this which confirms what I said: https://www.askthe.police.uk/content/Q360.htm or this: https://www.leicestermercury.co.uk/news/uk-world-news/legal-drive-car-without-mot-142846 or this: https://www.halfordsautocentres.com/advice/mot-advice/can-you-drive-without-an-mot

Comment: The first link says exactly what I said; you an drive a vehicle without MOT to a pre-arranges MOT inspection.  It remains an offence to drive any car that has a dangerous defect on the public road.  Driving a vehicle with a defective tyre may be dealt with by means of 3 points and a fine.

Comment: Sure, if you want to ignore the bits that backup my point, as well as ignoring the other 2 articles I linked.

Comment: @PhillHealey I know for a fact that driving a vehicle that does not meet the definition of roadworthy under the construction and use regulations section of the road traffic act leaves you liable to prosecution.  Will you personally cover the legal fees of any user of this site who follows your advice and subsequently is prosecuted?

Comment: Thats great! @Steve Mathews

Comment: I'm now on a PC, not a phone.  I'll draw particular attention to the passage " if you are stopped by the police you could still be prosecuted for any defective parts on your vehicle e.g. exhaust, brakes and tyres etc."  Not only does it specifically mention tyres but there is no indication that the user asking the question doesn't have a valid MOT or is driving a vehicle that requires one.  There is no exception in law to make a provision for driving a defective vehicle.  The links you have posted confirm this.